# Типизация объекта класса в Python

Tags: python, ооп, типизация, typing

У меня есть класс User и я сделал функцию, которая на вход принимает объект этого класса, вопрос как типизировать этот аргумент

```
class User:
    def __init__(self, *args): ...
    def something(self, user: ?): ...
```

Если поставить туда User то Python скажет:

```
NameError: name 'User' is not defined
```

Подскажите пожалуйста что делать? Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Вот несколько вариантов:

1. `__future__`:

```
from __future__ import annotations

class User:
    def __init__(self, *args): ...
    def something(self, user: User): ...
```

2. `typing`

```
from typing import TypeVar

t = TypeVar('User', bound='User')

class User:
    def __init__(self, *args): ...
    def something(self, user: t): ...
```

3. Просто строки:

```
class User:
    def __init__(self, *args): ...
    def something(self, user: 'User'): ...
```

---

Я бы рекомендовал использовать `__future__`, потому что он был [запланирован](https://docs.python.org/3/library/__future__.html#id1) как стандартное включение, но пока что релиз в стандарт отложили дважды.

Comment: Огоромное спасибо!